# Syntax of Constructor Defining

Tags: c++, constructor, definition

Why it is required to write class name with constructor name while defining a constructor outside the class?....does it make sense?..as the class name can be easily detected from the constructor's name as they must have the same name and as it has no return type we can differentiate it from other normal functions having same name as well.

Comment: Because everyone is accustomed with it already.  Standard is created from people's opinion, same as law.    It is like why we have to say "You are ..." rather than "You is" even when it is a singular. .... If you have some better idea about the syntax, you can propose it to the world/committee.

Comment: After the compiler sees e.g. `Foo(` then it have many alternatives: It could be a function declaration, a function definition, a cast, a creation of a `Foo` object and probably a few others. Adding another possible alternative will make it much harder for the compiler to figure out what's really happening. Furthermore, suddenly you would have two different syntaxes for creating member functions for a class, which makes it harder for the programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why it is required to write class name with constructor name while defining a constructor outside the class?....does it make sense?

Yes. Same as when defining any other method of the class.  The constructor is still a member of the class, and all member methods have to be scoped properly when defined outside of the class declaration.  Imagine what would happen if multiple classes in different namespaces have the same name.  Specifying the constructor name without scoping it by the namespace and class names would cause ambiguities.